# using onViewTransformed callback to setState() in the parent component causes infinite loop

Tags: react-native

I’m new in React Native so not sure if is it a bug or just my misunderstanding but there is an issue for me when I call the onViewTransformed callback like that

```
import Image from ‘react-native-transformable-image’;

class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.transform = this.transform.bind(this);
    this.state = {
       scale: 1,
       translateX: 0,
       translateY: 0
    };
  }

  handleTransform(data) {
    this.setState({
      scale: data.scale,
      translateX: data.translateX,
      translateY: data.translateY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Image
        ...
        onViewTransformed={this.transform}
        />
     );
  }
```

}

it goes to an infinite loop. 
React Native error sheet says that can be because of componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate method.

So what am I missing ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your definition of the `<Image />` component and where you use `onViewTransformed`.

My guess would be once `onViewTransformed` is called from `<Image />`, that runs `handleTransform` in Parent. This subsequently rerenders `<Image />` which triggers `onViewTransformed` again, rinse repeat we have an infinite loop.

Generally, setting state in render functions causes this. The two ways to resolve this would be to either

1 - remove any `setStates` in the `render` or `didUpdate` of any component. Find ways to accomplish the same desired behaviour outside of these life cycles.

2 - Really think through the order of execution and be careful to not trigger an infinite loop. (This tends to be bug prone the more you work on the app though).

This is all guess work though, if you could share more of your code, I'd be more than glad to help :)

Comment: The component <Image /> is a component of https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-transformable-image package and the onViewTransformed prop is inherited from https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-view-transformer. By the way is it allowed to setState in componentWillUpdate lifecycle ? And thank you so much.

Comment: it's best to not use setState in componentWillUpdate, look here for more info on why: https://github.com/DevelopmentArc/react-indepth/issues/3

Do you need to run `handleTransform` to store the state, do you use this state for anything? From the docs for react-native-view-transformer it looks like it will function just fine on it's own without the parent needing to make a copy of the transform?

Comment: I think, I actually don’t need to store it in the state. I just want to use the callback’s data to provide info to cropData option of ImageEditor’s cropImage() method.